# Multipart form-data request with sttp - Scala HTTP client

Tags: scala

How to do multipart form request using sttp library. Below is the sample curl request.

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:2004/v2/api/artifacts \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F file=@/Users/username/filename
```

Below is the scala code.

```
val request = sttp
      .multipartBody(multipart("file", new FileInputStream(filePath)))
      .post(uri"$mistApiUrl/v2/api/artifacts")
val response = request.send()
```

The field `file` is not being sent properly.

**Problem solved. Solution details [here](https://github.com/softwaremill/sttp/issues/173).**

Comment: May you attach the "not properly" send request? (e.g. [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) is a nice debugging utility...)

Comment: Only `Accept-Encoding` header is set in the request object. Not setting the `content-type` and boundary.

Comment: I setup the port forwarding to mitmproxy.
echo "
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 2004 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
" | sudo pfctl -ef -

Getting - HTTP protocol error in client request: Invalid HTTP request form (expected: authority or absolute, got: relative)

Comment: Have you tried to use another sttp backend? It might be a bug in the backend that you're currently using.

Comment: Tried `HttpURLConnectionBackend` and `AkkaHttpBackend`. Both of them aren't working.

Comment: Works after calling `fileName` function in multipart. Details [here](https://github.com/softwaremill/sttp/issues/173)

Comment: May you post your working code from github as accepted answer for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fileName` needs to be called upon using InputStream in multipart form-data.

```
val request = sttp
        .multipartBody(multipart("file", new FileInputStream(filePath)).fileName(fileName))
        .post(uri"$mistApiUrl/v2/api/artifacts")
```